# ¿Por qué cambian las vocales "i" de "a" en sustantivos derivada de verbos como estallido, bramido, ladrido?

Tags: gramática

Muchas veces la ortografía tiene razones de pronunciación como *día* y *ortografía* usando un acento para deshacer el diptongo. ¿Aquí hay un razon gramatical o histórica tal vez? Los participios pasados claramente siendo *bramado*, *ladrado*, *estallado*, etc. "Para distinguir entre el sustantivo del adjetivo" no es una respuesta suficiente. Hay muchos sustantivos hechos del participio pasado (por ejemplo el hecho).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay toda una serie de verbos relacionados con sonidos (o acciones que sugieren sonido o desplazamiento de aire) con derivados que terminan en *-ido*. Además de *ladrar, bramar, estallar* (los ya citados), están *soplar, silbar, balar, estampar, pitar, zumbar, chillar, bufar, chirriar, graznar, chasquear* y por supuesto el propio *sonar*, dentro de los de la primera conjugación, más *rugir, mugir, gruñir*, y [muchos otros](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Lista_de_voces_de_animales). Como señala Carlos Alejo en un comentario, *[-ido](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Kultj9v)* es un sufijo que se usa para derivar sonidos.

En general la razón por la cual una palabra se deriva de una manera y no de otra es arbitraria. El idioma castellano tiene muchas maneras diferentes para crear sustantivos a partir de verbos.

Con respecto a por qué no se derivan de participios estas palabras en particular: hay una gran diferencia entre los participios de verbos transitivos como *hacer*, *amar* o *pedir* y los de los verbos intransitivos como *bramar* o *estallar*. Los participios de los verbos transitivos, cuando se transforman en sustantivos, representan objetos directos de esos verbos, o los sujetos de sus formas pasivas:

- un *hecho* = alguien hizo X = X fue hecho
- su *amado* = ella amó a X = X fue amado
- el *pedido* = alguien pidió X = X fue pedido

No se puede hacer esto mismo con *bramar* o *estallar*, porque son intransitivos. El significado del sustantivo producido por la derivación en *-ido* no es el mismo que en los verbos de más arriba; éstos representan la acción en sí, no su objeto:

- un *bramido* = la acción de bramar (alguien bramó)
- un *estallido* = la acción de estallar (algo estalló)

Pero como decía, esto es arbitrario, ya que existen muchos verbos cuyo sustantivo de acción es igual al participio:

- *[bordado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5tpBIoh)* (acción de bordar)
- *llegada*
- *[pitada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TENhk9R)* (acción de sonar el pito o silbato)
- *[parada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RpRAesx%7CRpSGwPJ)* (acción de parar o detenerse)

Estos verbos los elegí porque son al menos opcionalmente intransitivos y de la primera conjugación (infinitivo en *-ar*), como los del ejemplo, pero lo mismo ocurre con otros:

- *mordida*
- *acometida*
- *zambullida*

Por alguna razón la mayoría de estos derivados del participio que representan acciones son de género femenino. Pero también hay derivados que no representan propiamente acciones ni pacientes, como *decorado* (sinónimo de *decoración*) o *cableado* (el conjunto de los cables de una instalación), que casualmente o no resultan ser masculinos.

Como se ve, hay una variedad de maneras de formar derivados sustantivos a partir de los verbos en castellano, incluso sin alejarse mucho de los participios. No hay una regla que los englobe a todos.

Comment: De hecho, sí: [**_-ido_**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Kultj9v) "forma sustantivos que significan sonidos".

Comment: Creo que deberían ser las dos cosas, ya que la pregunta era por qué no se derivaban de participios estas palabras, pero por supuesto lo de @CarlosAlejo es lo que va al punto. Voy a editar la respuesta, que lamentablemente creo que fue aceptada demasiado rápido...